# Strange behavior of disabled property for table element

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

So this is small wrapped up HTML element in one of the .aspx pages served on a website.

```html
<table id="ucDemographics_tdDemographic" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tbody> 
    <!--   inner html code removed for readability purspose  -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

One of the js functions is trying to access this element by id and do perform some logic:

```js
function Validate() {
  
    // dropdown for physican name
    var physicVal = document.getElementById('ucDemographics_uxddlPhysicianName').value; 
  
    // Empty physicianName validation
    if (physicVal == "-1") {
        window.alert('Validation(s) failed');
        physicVal.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Empty nurseName validation
    var tablebyID = document.getElementById('ucDemographics_tdDemographic');
    if (tablebyID.disabled == false) {
      
        // dropdown for nurse name
        var nurseVal = $("#ucDemographics_uxGENurse").val() ;
      
        if ( nurseVal == "-1") {
            window.alert('Validation(s) failed');
            nurseVal.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
  
  return true;
}
```

My question is how this code segment in above Validate function able to access the disabled property, since it's selecting a table tag and they don't support disabled property as far as my understanding goes.

```
var tablebyID = document.getElementById('ucDemographics_tdDemographic');
if (tablebyID.disabled == false) {  }
```

Here is a snapshot of my chrome debugger:

[image]

**Edit 01:** The Validate function is called upon when onClick() event triggers on the submit button.

Comment: Browsers are perfectly fine with JavaScript code adding random properties to DOM nodes. Why is your code doing that? Well, I have no idea, and I don't know how anybody else would know either.

Comment: @Pointy but the thing is by the coding logic if either one of the two dropdowns has value property set to -1, at that time the tableID variable let's you access the disabled property. But If i do the following steps in sequential order i.e., `Both dropdown elements values are set to -1. and click save button` -> `Then alert message pops up as no physician name is not selected` -> `So, we select a physician from the dropdown and again click on Save button` It is during these series of actions when we cannot access the disabled property.

Comment: @Pointy I think I got your point, thnx for helping. Somebody must have manually set up 
`disabled` as a custom property

Comment: Yea, to me it's a slightly weird thing to do, but not really outrageous or anything. Personally I'd do it by adding/removing a "marker" class to the element, one that has nothing to do with styling.